# How to make a profile pic animation like WhatsApp?

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapp, flutter-animation, sliverappbar

I want to make a profile picture animation-like in WhatsApp. In particular, while the user scrolls upwards, I need the profle picture to move up and shrink into the app bar.

In flutter, I'm expecting a titoe of that WhatsApp profile.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! When asking questions, add images if necessary to show what you want to achieve. Also you need to post at least some code, or research you've done to prove you've tried to find a solution yourself. As for the question, a SliverAppBar may help you https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html